# PHP:Wrong Login info does not redirect to the specific page

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include 'lib/db_conn.php';
$uid=$_REQUEST['uid'];
$pass=$_REQUEST['pass'];
if(($uid==NULL && $pass==NULL) ||($uid==NULL) ||($pass==NULL))
{
    header("location:index.php?msg=Fields can't be left blank..");
}

$pass=md5($pass);
$sql1="SELECT * FROM `tb_user` WHERE `email`='$uid' AND `pass`='$pass'";
$rs1=mysql_query($sql1) or die (mysql_error());
$row1=mysql_fetch_array($rs1) or die (mysql_error());
$email=$row1['email'];
if($uid==$email)
{
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['id']=$row1['id'];
        header("location:home.php");
}
else
{
header("location:index.php?msg=Wrong Credentials..");
}
?>
```

Comment: `if(($uid==NULL && $pass==NULL) ||($uid==NULL) ||($pass==NULL))`... is excessive.  The OR case means the AND case isn't necessary

Comment: The `Location:` header should be followed by an absoluteURI, including the protocol. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is better not to write a message in the address bar but just tokenize it, i.e.:

```
header("location:index.php?msg=wcred");
```

and in the index.php:

```
if ($_GET['msg'] == "wcred") echo "Wrong Credentials..";
```

And, as Kai mentioned, `$uid=$_REQUEST['uid'];` must be

```
$uid=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['uid']);
```

Also, as dnagirl mentioned, field emptiness checking is wrong.
Also, as I am to mention, `exit` must follow any location header

```
<?php
if((empty($_REQUEST['uid']) OR empty($_REQUEST['pass'])) {
    header("location:index.php?msg=fempty");
    exit;
}
include 'lib/db_conn.php';

$pass=md5($_REQUEST['pass']);
$pass=mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
$uid=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['uid']);

$sql1="SELECT * FROM `tb_user` WHERE `email`='$uid' AND `pass`='$pass'";
$rs1=mysql_query($sql1) or die (mysql_error());
$row1=mysql_fetch_array($rs1) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
if($row1) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id']=$row1['id'];
    header("location:home.php");
    exit;
} else {
    header("location:index.php?msg=wcred");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the code tag. It's ugly to read.

I think you should not type "Wrong Credentials.." as is, the letters should be URL encoded. Also, you should exit() the execution after sending the header() -calls.

By the way, you should escape $uid or you could get into trouble with SQL injections.